# Renaming a file name in Unix

Tags: unix, rename, ksh

We need to rename the file from *filename.dat.dat.dat* to *filename.dat*. We have plenty of files having somewhat the same type of name having extension *.dat.dat.dat*.

Using the below script:

```
cd /home/riya
for file in filename.dat.dat.dat
do
    echo $file
    new = "${file:0:12}"
    echo $new
    mv $file $new
done
```

Giving the below error:

```
riya.ksh[5]: "${file:0:12}": bad substitution
```

Comment: I suppose this is not a unix question, but a `ksh` question? Unix has had many shells, and the `${file:0:12}` expression is not a traditional shell expression.

Answer (score 0):

Unless these filenames all consist of exactly eight characters followed by `.dat` repeated three times, you would probably be better off using regular expressions to modify them. A utility like [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) can do this without any trouble.

Your question is a little unclear as to where these `.dat` files are located, but if they're all in the same directory then this ought to work:

```sh
for f in *.dat.dat.dat
  do
    g=$(echo $f | sed s/\\.dat\\.dat//)
    echo "$f -> $g" ; mv $f $g
  done
```

Comment: thanks a lot.... that resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

[r3mainer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70566300/renaming-a-file-name-in-unix/70567474#70567474) is possible, but its feasibility depends on how many such files there are: using [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) (or any other external program for that matter - [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), [tr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)), ...) will need to spawn a complete new subprocess and its environment which is quite taxing on the system.

Fortunately, the functionality of your sed-script can be achieved within the shell by using "parameter substitution".

@riva: first off, you code can't work because variable assignments are not allowed to have blanks in them:

```
 new = "${file:0:12}"    # Wrong!
 new="${file:0:12}"      # Correct!
```

Even the second one will work only depending on which shell exactly you are using. ksh88 for instance (the default shell in [AIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX)) will not, ksh93 (the only [KornShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell) version in Linux and named "enhanced Korn shell" in AIX) will understand that.

Still, @r3mainer's criticism holds: this works only if all the filenames are guaranteed to be eight characters long. Instead, you can use parameter substitution to get what you want:

```
 new="filename.dat.dat.dat"
 echo ${new%%.dat*}          # This will yield "filename"
 new="${new%%.dat*}.dat"     # This will yield "filename.dat"
```

The expansion `${variable%%pattern}` cuts `pattern` (in its longest possible form, "greedy match") from the end of the contents of `variable`. Since the pattern is ".dat*", this means everything starting with the first (of arbitrarily many) ".dat" sequences is cut. Then a single ".dat" is added at the end.

Additionally, notice that you shouldn't use *for* loops for this kind of activity. [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)) is the command for this sort of purpose:

```
 find /some/directory -type f -name "*.dat" -print |\
 while read FILE ; do
      mv "${FILE}" "${FILE%%.dat*}.dat"
 done
```

Comment: Who is *"riva"*? Do you mean *"Riya"*?